# Copy current row and insert it below whenever I update a cell in a specific column of excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a simple To Do list for myself in excel. As part of 1 of the function, I would like below.

Currently I write current status in Column F (Current Status) in the excel. If I update any cell in this column to "Subtask", then a macro should automatically copy the row where i updated Subtask and insert it below the current row (Except the value of cell mentioning 'Subtask'). I tweaked a code but it seems with an earlier version excel kept copying rows as with each copy a new cell with Subtask was created. I have tried couple of different options but none seem to work (I have very very little experience in VBA).

Codes I have tried till now (All hangs the excel)

```
Set StatusCol = Range("F2:F101")
For Each Status In StatusCol
    If Status = "Subtask" Then
        Status.EntireRow.Copy
        Status.Insert
    End If
Next Status
```

Another code I tried

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "Subtask" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Copy
        Target.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
        Target.Offset(1, -5).Paste
End If
```

Both doesn't seem to work at all. Can you please help?

Complete code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    'This code sorts based on C column
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B1:M100").Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
    'This code resets based on value of Reset in Cell R3
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N2:N2")) Is Nothing Then
        Set Target = Range("N2")
        If Target.Value = "Reset" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A100").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("C2").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("A2").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    End If
    'This code fills value Now variable in row 8 when something is written in G column
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value = Int(Now())
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where have you input your change event and what type of change event are you using?  Both are important for posting your code for these types of questions.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand, I don't really code much (and this is my 1st question on StackOverflow)

Comment: When you are inputting this code for a change event, you need to include your line reading `sub worksheet_change(by target as val)` etc.  You also need to specify the name of the module you are working in, e.g., a standard module, a class module, workbook module.  All of these impact how this code should run and whether or not it *can* run.

Comment: Oh, I have updated the code above.